# Get lost Xcode binary from archive in organizer?

Tags: ios, xcode, binary, archive

Alright, so I had been having issues with this and never resolved them, finished my app and published it before this caused major problems -

I have pods installed for my Xcode project so I had been working off a workspace. I had always backed up in the past by copy pasting my project folder then renaming, however more recently something happened that cause every change to my workspace to affect all previous versions.

I tried everything  - saving to external hard drive, github, etc but I just ended up going on working on the workspace and making sure I didn't screw anything up. Along with this issue whenever I clicked on the Xcode project that is in the project folder, none of my new code would be there.

That Xcode project version was from several months back and the only way to see my new code was to click on the workspace. I asked a question about this but no one had an answer.

A week ago I finished the app, archived and uploaded to App store. It is now published, however I want to update so today I went to my workspace and the project file above the pods file was RED meaning not there.

I have no idea why this would have happened. Dragging the Xcode project i  the folder to the workspace again, just runs the very old version.

I need to get my binary back and solve this problem. Im desperate. I have this:

[image]

One of the export options is save for development and such.. Is there a way to get my binary back from this archive? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What good is extracting the binary from the archive? It won't have anything you need to fix your project.

Comment: Isn't the binary the whole project? Is there a way to get the code from apple.. anywhere?

Comment: No, the binary isn't remotely close to the project. Unless you have used some form of backup or source code control, you won't get much from binary.

Comment: How can I backup in the future? Whenever I push a previous version to github when I sync and take down that old version open the workspace it just loads the new code